# HTML/CSS code problem - background image + alpha

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my first simple web page.

I am using Visual Studio Code and from time to time it does not work as it should - when I save my progress web page does not show changes but when I restart all (VSC and web page) it works but sometimes I must do this several times. So I do not know why it is happening.

When I reached the lesson about creating a landing page I encountered a problem with placing the background color. I already have my wallpaper and would like to put semi-alpha black background on it but somehow I can't.

Below you can see my current code in HTML and CSS:

```css
    .landing-page {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('bg.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    }

    .landing-page-shadow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    }
```

```html
 <body>
    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <a class="nav-logo" href="index.html">nazwa firmy</a>

            <div class="nav-links">
                <a href="#">o nas</a>
                <a href="#">oferta</a>
                <a href="#">kontakt</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="landing-page">
    <div class="landing-page-shadow"></div>
    </section>
    </body>
```

The black background doesn't show at all even before I applied alpha.
It is also interesting that when I put my code into CodePen it shows all correctly. Hmmm...

Comment: Hi, I don't see any issue with it, aren't you able to preview the grayish background color? Just remove the background image and you will see it

Comment: you have an element having a picture as background (that you called _black_ in your question) and its child putting a layer of opacity above it. Your style is actually working correctly if you reference an existing image (in this case it was `url('bg.jpg')`). So your problem is how you are hosting the website you are testing. To make it simpler you could try hosting your page on the filesystem without involving any web server as long as the code you are testing is that simple

Comment: I was just double clicking index.html file and it was always oppening in browser. Until now sooner or later but i could see all changes that I saved in VSC. Now I installed LiveServer and it shows the change as it should. Thank you.